# Find the basis of given set $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $W = \{ A \in \mathbb{M}_3(\mathbb{R}) |A^T  = -A \ \text{and }\sum_{j=1}^{3} a_{1j} =0\}$.

write  down the basis for $W$

## My attempt :

acoording to the given  condtion $W = \begin{bmatrix}  1 &-1&0\\1&0&-1  \\ 0& 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Now $\begin{bmatrix}  1 &-1&0\\1&0&-1  \\ 0& 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}   = a\begin{bmatrix}  1 &0&0\\0&0&0  \\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + (-b)  \begin{bmatrix}  0 &1&0\\0&0&0  \\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + d\begin{bmatrix}  0 &0&0\\1&0&0  \\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + h \begin{bmatrix}  0 &0&0\\0&0&0  \\ 0& 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} + (-f)\begin{bmatrix}  0 &0&0\\0&0&1  \\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}  a &-b&c\\d&e&-f  \\ g& h & i \end{bmatrix}= aB_1 + (-b) B_2  + dB_3 +hB_4  +(-f)B_5$

Now  here  i got $5$ linearly independent elements in $W$.

Is  my answer  is coorect or not ??

Pliz verified  and tell me

Comment: if $A=-A^T$ with the entries in $\mathbb{R}$, can a diagonal element be non zero??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not correct. In what you wrote, $W$ stands for a set of matrices and also for an individual matrix. That doesn't make sense. Besides, your matrix $W$ does not belong to the set $W$.

The matrices of $W$ are those of the form$$\begin{pmatrix}0&a&-a\\-a&0&b\\a&-b&0\end{pmatrix},$$which is equal to$$a\begin{pmatrix}0&1&-1\\-1&0&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$Therefore, a basis of $W$ will be$$\left(\begin{pmatrix}0&1&-1\\-1&0&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}\right).$$